# It is possible to use result from sql aggregate function from other table as a field value in table?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, aggregate, average

I am trying to use result value from MySQL avg() function a field in other table, but i dont know how to do it. I was looking for similar questions but i didn't find any.

That's how my database looks like :

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zao0.png)

books                      books_ratings

---

id_book:    int(11)        id_ragin:   int(11)
title:      varchar(55)    id_book:    int(11)
avg_rating: float          rating:     int(11)
id_client:  int(11)

[books table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHDLp.png)

### id_book | title | avg_rating

1      ...     NULL
2      ...     NULL
3      ...     NULL

[books_ratings table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Jl5.png)

### id_rating | id_book | rating | id_client

1           1        5         1
2           1        4         2
3           2        5         1

Im using that query to get the information I want, to use them as fields in "books" table :

```
SELECT books_ratings.id_book, AVG(books_ratings.rating) AS avg_rating
FROM books_ratings
GROUP BY books_ratings.id_book;
```

[aggregate query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1k4b.png)

### id_book | ang_rating |

1           4.25
2           3.00

How can I use those values to get something like this below ?

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViHDo.png)

### id_book | title | ang_rating |

1        ...       4.25
2        ...       3.00

I was trying to use functions in mysql, but i dont know how to use them to get something like this below :

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViHDo.png)

### id_book | title | ang_rating |

1        ...       4.25
2        ...       3.00

Comment: Please include all possible relevant information as text in the question and please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I cant post images ...